# rails 3 - Raising an exception? Using Begin, Rescue and Raising Expections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting the following error:

```
MailingJob failed with NameError: uninitialized constant MailingJob::MissingInfo - 2 failed attempts
```

My code:

```
class MailingJob < Struct.new(:mailing_id)
  def perform
    begin
       @message_reply = ....
       raise MissingInfo, "Message reply not found" if @message_reply.length == 0
       .....
    rescue MissingInfo => detail
        Rails.logger.info "RESCUED - MissingInfo,RESCUED - MissingInfo, RESCUED - MissingInfo, RESCUED - MissingInfo, RESCUED - MissingInfo"
        Rails.logger.info detail
    end

  end
```

This is my first time using begin/rescue, suggestions,help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use an undefined constant. You must define the exception class:

```
class MissingInfo < StandardError; end
```

Secondly, I wouldn't rely on the logs to capture the errors. Instead, I would use a service such as [Hoptoad](http://hoptoadapp.com) for that.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I want to be able to use: raise MissingInfo, "Email model type not found", @message, @person   how do I make it so resuce MissingInfo can provide me with those 3 vars inside?

Comment: @AnApprentice: Set the variables before the exception is raised, they will be available in the rescue.

Comment: Thanks Ryan that worked but detail did not... Inside of rescue MissingInfo => detail, detail is outputting as Detail: MailingJob::MissingInfo and not the string I set when I raised the exception. ideas?